# Display glitch on recent activities for suggested edit to subsequently-deleted tag wikis

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, recent-activity, information-display, deleted-posts

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314880) to a tag wiki that was apparently subsequently deleted. In my recent activities list, there is a UI glitch: it shows up as "suggested edit on" [nothing]. That is, the text of the link is empty.

The relevant part of the HTML is:

```
<tr>
<td>
<div class="date" title="2012-07-12 22:18:50Z">1d</div></td>
<td>
<span title="suggested an edit to this post">suggested</span></td>
<td>
<a href="/suggested-edits/314880">suggested edit</a> on <b><a href="/questions/11435603/" class="question-hyperlink"></a></b></td>
</tr>
```